# how to solve 50 noodles/shoelaces puzzle?

Tags: math, puzzle

There are 50 noodles in a bowl. You can tie two ends of either one noodle or two different noodles, forming a nod.

Q: What is the expected value of number of loops we can have in the bowl?

Comment: Am I the only one not understanding what this question is doing here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be programming related (and if it is, it should be edited to include more detail)

Comment: I edited the question and have asked another one. Please remove the hold so I can get help on this one

Comment: @suyashgautam if you want to ask a new question, ask a _new_ question. Do not edit a prior question to completely change its contents. I'm reverting the edit.

Comment: Understood! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*∑(1/i)* for *i* from *1* to *50*.

When you have **n** noodles lets take a look at noodle number **n**. It can either be tied to itself with probability **1/n** or some other noodle with probability **(n-1)/n**. When it gets tied to itself the loop is formed and we need to find the expected value for the rest **n-1** noodles. When it gets tied to some other noodle then it is the same as we have taken away this noodle so the answer is expected value for the rest **n-1** noodles.

*f(n) = 1/n * (f(n-1) + 1) + (n-1)/n * f(n-1);*

*f(n) = 1/n * f(n-1) + 1/n + (n-1)/n * f(n-1);*

*f(n) = f(n-1) + 1/n*

*f(n) = 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you also please explain the logic?

Comment: @suyash gautam, added.